# flushleft by using gb4e.sty

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, linguistics, gb4e

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{gb4e,qtree,skull}


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex\emph{Superiority-obeying and Superiority-violating multiple
\emph{wh}-questions}
\begin{xlist}
\ex {\textit{Which} student read \textit{which} book? }
\ex {{\em Which} book did {\em which} student read ?}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

and the output came as:
[image]

How can I get the entries starts from the left margin, please advise...